# Open source software for transmitting pictures from balloons

Tags: open-source, data-transfer

I'm looking for some ways to transmit pictures from a high altitude balloon.

Is there any open-source software for dealing with this over radio?

Comment: Do you have all of the needed hardware already? Or are you looking for a hardware+software solution?

Comment: Your question might be on-topic at http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Some problems simply cannot be solved by software. Being a radio amateur, I'd say that there are solutions. Questions are: what amount of data do you want to transfer in what time. This gives us an idea about the bandwidth. You'd then need to check if you're allowed to use radio frequencies for that purpose, e.g. are you a radio amateur as well? (I doubt, otherwise you would not have asked this question)

Comment: I don't have any hardware yet, but i want to find some open sources first (arduino, lora etc).

Comment: @ThomasWeller  yes, i am

Comment: @JanDoggen did you see my answer which cites Hardwar with a 1km wifi range? That might well be enough, depending on the definition of high altitude. Hmm, now I am picturing a bunch of balloons, spaced 0.9km apart vertically, with wifi repeaters :-)

Comment: MUST it be radio? I have posted two alternative hardware solutions - are you open to such?

Comment: @Mawg I just did, yes. But it's better to leave the technology open. Removing my first comment.

Comment: I guess that we won't ever see an answer to this very interesting question :-(

Comment: Although, [this](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/tlewis/high-altitude-arduino-raspberry-pi-project-haarpp) does look **very** interesting

Comment: So frustrating!!  guy signs up, asks a single question, then never returns to SE. I would ***really*** have liked to have known if something worked for this particular question.

Comment: Hackaday managed [720km transmission](https://hackaday.com/2017/09/11/the-things-network-sets-702-km-distance-record-for-lorawan/) from a balloon at 35km

Comment: Your question can be reopened if you already know the hardware. If not, please ask at hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com thanks!

Comment: You might want to contact whoever launched the [High-Altitude Arduino/Raspberry Pi Project (HAARPP)](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/tlewis/high-altitude-arduino-raspberry-pi-project-haarpp) It didn't get funding, alas, but they might still be able to help

Comment: Also, take a look at https://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/09/12/lohan_rockblock/

Comment: Related http://www.daveakerman.com/?p=2019

Comment: `Last seen Nov 9 '16 at 13:28` - two hours after posting the question. I doubt that we will ever see an accepted answer, but please let's keep contributing to this, as it is an intriguing and interesting question, especially as technology evolves

Comment: See also [Multi-Purpose Data Acquisition Board for a Sounding Balloon](https://www.elektormagazine.com/labs/elektorpost-no-17-multi-purpose-data-acquisition-board-for-a-sounding-balloon)

Comment: https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/article/lorawan-distance-world-record ... Servet is a citizen science project supported by Ibercivis and a growing team of volunteers. The project’s aim is to give people the opportunity to conduct stratospheric experiments using weather balloons  ... the new world record  is 766 km (476 miles).. It uses LoRaWAN

Comment: I can't explain why I am fascinated by this question & continue to visit it with potential answers (I only wish that it could be re-opened, but ..) Anyhoo, https://hackaday.com/2021/04/09/uplink-system-for-high-altitude-balloons/

Comment: Also form Hackaday : [RASPBERRY PI ZERO BEAMS BACK VIDEO FROM 100,000 FEET](https://hackaday.com/2021/03/26/raspberry-pi-zero-beams-back-video-from-100000-feet/)

Answer (score 1):

Some hints - For transmission from balloons you are likely to wish to minimise:

a) Weight &
 b) Power Requirements

To minimise these you usually need to minimise bandwidth and allow for transmission errors so first I would suggest considering using a good compression that also allows you to see what is coming down - I would look at progressive jpeg encoding - plenty of Open Source tools to support this.

You might also like to take a look at [LoPy](https://www.pycom.io/solutions/py-boards/lopy/) as a possible platform - with very low power requirements and [LoRa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LPWAN) integrated it could be a very good starting point.

Comment: This looks very good and very reasonably priced (https://www.pycom.io/webshop/) BUT, can it cover the distance to "high altitude"?

Comment: @Mawg - http://www.postscapes.com/long-range-wireless-iot-protocol-lora/ gives a good write up but with an expected unobstucted range of 20 miles you are well into the Stratosphere. As pointed out you could launch a series of balloons to act as relays to get to higher altitudes still.

Comment: This specification sheet offers 40km range so even better and the temperature range of -40C..+85C looks good as well - at €29.95 it could well be worth giving it a go.

Comment: At that price, I want to buy two & play with them!

Comment: For a similar project see http://www.pridopia.co.uk/pi-p-hab.html

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in open source Iridium modems.
There are a few, separate and incorporated in [cubesats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CubeSat) I think.
https://github.com/tudelft/iridium

Sparkfun also sells some.
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13745

So now you at least have a physical layer to get stacks for.

Maybe open source does not get the quality you are looking for here, but functionally changing the modem would, in theory, not be necessary.

Comment: That's very interesting, and the unit cost is cheaper than SkyWave. Where would I buy airtime for the Sparkfun Iridium modem? And is there a limit on the amount of data that I can transmit? I have to say, though, that I am ***extremely*** impressed by SkyWave's development & test environment.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your range, but if 1km would be enough for you, then I would recommend [Flutter](http://flutterwireless.com/) (see also completed [Kickstarter page](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/flutterwireless/flutter-20-wireless-arduino-with-half-mile-1km-ran) for more info).

It's a US $20 Arduino board with 1kmn wifi range (which it should reach vertically, as there are unlikely to be obstructions)).

That's about it really, so now for the obligatory  graphic

[image]

---

[Update] if necessary ... a bunch of balloons, spaced 0.9km apart vertically, with wifi repeaters

Answer (score 0):

I have had lots of fun with Skywave’s offerings (they have now rebranded as OrbComm), and you might like to look at the [IDP_800](http://www.orbcomm.com/en/hardware/devices/skywave-idp-800).

Read [the datasheet](http://www.orbcomm.com/PDF/datasheet/IDP-800-Trailer-Tracking.pdf).

Mass: with batteries: 1.3 Kg (with integrated antenna Dimensions : 43.2 cm x 14.7 cm x 2.5 cm and it runs on 6 AA batteries, which can be bought almost anywhere.

I send only one 50 byte message a day & they tell me that I can except a three year battery life. Their units generally cost US $500 - $1,000 (with discount for bulk purchases), and their airtime rates are competitive.

The device has built in GPDS and is fully programmable in the LUA scripting language.

Note that this is not an open source software solution - is that really what you want?

Obligatory picture follows:
[image]